# Wordpress pagination translation

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, pagination

there is a multilingual (English + Arabic) website using qTranslate X plugin for translation. Everything is working fine but there is no translation effect on pagination like I want "Next 1,2" text(Next/Previous) and numbers will be translate into Arabic when user select the Arabic version of website.

I have used

```
echo paginate_links($args);
```

it only works for text(Next/Previous) not numbers. Please suggest if is there any plugin or other way out?

Comment: Did you check my code, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**qtrans_getLanguage()**](http://princessdesign.net/wpsnippets/qtranslate/) functions.

**Example:**

```
if(qtrans_getLanguage() == "en"){ // Enter YOUR ENGLISH LANGUAGE CODE
    echo paginate_links( array( 'prev_text' => __('« Prev'), 'next_text' => __('Next »') );
}elseif(qtrans_getLanguage() == "ar"){ // ENTER YOUR ARABIC LANGUAGE CODE
    echo paginate_links( array( 'prev_text' => __('« السابق'), 'next_text' => __('التالى »') );
}
```

For the Target specific language in the theme template

Comment: Thanks for writing in. I have already said I'm able to translate Prev and Next text through echo paginate_links($args);
I need translation of pagination numbering like 1,2,3... into Arabic when user select arabic version.. thanks